# Different formater & linter configurations for subdirectories using Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a project with the following structure

```
project/
  backend-in-python/
  frontend-in-typescript/
    .eslintrc.js
    .prettierrc.js
    ...
```

How to setup VSCode extensions (Python, ESlint, Prettier) to use the configuration files inside the directory ?

Answer (score 0):

**Workspace Settings** can achieve your goals.

Open the Settings editor from the **Command Palette** with **Preferences: Open Settings**:

[image]

After creating `Workspace settings.json`, it would be stored in folder `.vscode` under your current project, then you can add configurations about extensions to it, which will be applied to project.

Detailed information please view [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).